# Syncing local and online github repos

Tags: git, github

There are so many tutorials on github and all of them are too complicated for the beginner like me. Please let me know if I can use the following setup for github.

I have my local windows network. Each developer is working from his own machine inside the network. I want to maintain a local repository on my server so each dev. can commit files and use git on my windows server,

Then since I have the online github account I want to sync the repository on my server with the online one so they can work from home as well, Can I do that? Or what would be the recommended procedure?

PS: putting a static IP and making my server accessible from outside is out of the question.

Comment: Yes, this basically just means setting up multiple remotes to push to. However, if you're going to sync to GitHub anyway, perhaps just use that as your primary remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply:

- create an empty repo on GitHub
- add that repo as a remote on your local rpeo
- mirror push it

Locally:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo/on/your/server
git remote add github https://yourAccount@github.com/yourAccount/yourProject
git push --mirror
```